# Manga where the protagonist gets letters of recommendation from powerful figures, and changes his age, to go to a school

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I am trying to find the manga where the main character gets a letter of introduction from the Spirit King, Demon King, and the Dragon King.

- He also uses his power to change his age so that he can get in the school.
- He had a supposedly legendary bird to get the letters.
- He went to school with the Demon King's daughter who at first he thought was a son.
- The introduction letters caused a huge commotion between the teachers and principal.
  -On the first day of school he summoned the spirit king, which broke a barrier.
- He was a guy who fought the demon king after the hero lost.
- Magic school.
- Everyone had human like features.
- He joined the school with a girl from an aristocrat family.
- He knew ancient magic but wanted to learn new magic.
- He was in a tower studying books for a few centuries.
- Seen by elves as a heroic figure of some sorts.

I don't remember if it was in color or black and white.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question really needs more details.  Please review the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit] in any additional details you can think of.  As it is, this question may get closed because it doesn't have enough information.

Comment: That is a good start. What sort of school was this? Was this a school for demons? For magic users? Regular prep school? Is this a world of open magic, or is this a secret? Contemporary? Fantasy medieval? Futuristic? Were most of the characters human, or at least look human?

Comment: It was the last one thank you

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Monogatari no Naka no Hito](http://myanimelist.net/manga/75553/Monogatari_no_Naka_no_Hito?) (A person in the story)*

> A young noblewoman once dreamed of becoming a magic user like in the
> old tales, but her time in magic school has dimmed her passion. One
> day, a mysterious man comes to her rescue in the forest, using magic
> like in the old stories. Despite the fact that he is clearly skilled
> in magic, he is thrilled by the idea of learning new techniques. Since
> the only way to do that in this day and age is in magic school, he
> alters his appearance to school-age and decides to accompany her back
> to school!
>
> [image]